# How can i disable Selenium DevTools with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use Python and Selenium last version.
I tried with this code... But nothing... I can't disable chrome devtools...
What can i do? Is it a bug or code problem?
I tried so many solutions.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-devtools")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get("http://selenium.dev")

time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

I want to disable chrome devtools.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlgOh.png)